# language management system

Tags: php, gettext

using gettext to provide multilingual service. but I need a language management system like facebook's translation or twitter's translation system.

a system which one accepts new translations via browser and compiles and saves locale files when click to "save" button.

is there anything like this? for php and gettext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this service finally : https://poeditor.com/login/

Not doing same thing what I said before but it's something :)

Answer (score 0):

See below URL I think it is very help full to you:-

[What to use for localization (php/smarty/pear application)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852242/what-to-use-for-localization-php-smarty-pear-application)

Gettext a mature system and provides features like singular/plural versions of translations. To be not dependant on the availability of the php extension, you should fall back to http://launchpad.net/php-gettext which provides a pure php implementation of gettext.

gettext has also the big advantage that dozens of tools exist that make it easy to translate those files.